# find only parent records with children of certain status across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, anti-join

I need all tickets where all the related children records are of status closed. So if one of the children is something else, I don't want the ticket in the result set.

I tried this using the antijoin patern, but my problem is that the children live in different tables.

please see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/febde/8
for a example

t1: ticket
t2: relatedrecord
t3: child1
t4: child1

```
select ticket.ticketid, rr.relatedrecordkey, rr.relatedrecordclass, c1.id, c1.status, c2.id, c2.status
from ticket
inner join relatedrecord rr on rr.recordkey = ticket.ticketid and rr.class = ticket.class
left join child1 c1 on c1.id = rr.relatedreckey and c1.class = rr.relatedrecclass
left join child2 c2 on c2.id = rr.relatedreckey and c2.class = rr.relatedrecclass
```

results in:

```
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ticketid | status | RECORDKEY | class | RELATEDRECCLASS | relatedreckey |   id   | status |   id   | status |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1183 | NEW    |      1183 | SR    | WORKORDER       |          1238 | 1238   | NEW    | (null) | (null) |
|     1183 | NEW    |      1183 | SR    | SR              |          1184 | (null) | (null) | 1184   | NEW    |
|     1185 | NEW    |      1185 | SR    | WORKORDER       |          1239 | 1239   | CLOSE  | (null) | (null) |
|     1185 | NEW    |      1185 | SR    | SR              |          1186 | (null) | (null) | 1186   | CLOSE  |
|     1187 | NEW    |      1187 | SR    | WORKORDER       |          1240 | 1240   | CLOSE  | (null) | (null) |
|     1187 | NEW    |      1187 | SR    | SR              |          1188 | (null) | (null) | 1188   | NEW    |
|     1190 | NEW    |      1190 | SR    | SR              |          1191 | (null) | (null) | 1191   | CLOSE  |
|     1192 | NEW    |      1192 | SR    | WORKORDER       |          1241 | 1241   | CLOSE  | (null) | (null) |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

so

- ticket 1183 has two related records, both not closed yet. (reject)
- ticket 1185 has two related records, both are closed (accept)
- ticket 1187 has two related records, one is new, one is closed. (reject)
- ticket 1190 has one related record which is closed (accept)
- ticket 1192 has one related record (different table) which is closed (accept)
- ticket 1189 has no related records (reject)

From this set, I only want to see ticket 1185, 1190, 1192 in the resultset.
it should look like:

```
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ticketid | status | RECORDKEY | class | RELATEDRECCLASS | relatedreckey |   id   | status |   id   | status |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1185 | NEW    |      1185 | SR    | WORKORDER       |          1239 | 1239   | CLOSE  | (null) | (null) |
|     1185 | NEW    |      1185 | SR    | SR              |          1186 | (null) | (null) | 1186   | CLOSE  |
|     1190 | NEW    |      1190 | SR    | SR              |          1191 | (null) | (null) | 1191   | CLOSE  |
|     1192 | NEW    |      1192 | SR    | WORKORDER       |          1241 | 1241   | CLOSE  | (null) | (null) |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+-----------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I tried something like:

```
select ticket.ticketid, rr.relatedrecordkey, rr.relatedrecordclass, c1.id, c1.status, c2.id, c2.status
from ticket
inner join relatedrecord rr on rr.recordkey = ticket.ticketid and rr.class = ticket.class
where not exists (
    select 1 from child1 c1
    where c1.id = rr.relatedreckey and c1.class = rr.relatedrecclass
    and c1.status <> 'CLOSE'
) and not exists (
    select 1 from child2 c2
    where c2.id = rr.relatedreckey and c2.class = rr.relatedrecclass
    and c2.status <> 'CLOSE'
)
```

This results in the two lines for ticket2 AND one from ticket 3 (since it has one child closed)
I'm a bit puzzeled how to solve this correctly.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I added a sqlfiddle with sample data

Comment: Is this for mysql or sql server? Your fiddle is mysql but you have this tagged as sqlserver.

Comment: I'm not sure if that matters for this question. I might need similar things for oracle, sqlserver and db2

Comment: I don't how to do this in mysql but in sqlserver you could use a recursive cte to traverse the entire hierarchy.

Comment: here is the SQL server variation. I added a few more corner cases, but the problem is the same. ticket 1187 should not be in the result set http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/febde/4

Comment: With your new sample why should 1185 be returned? It also have a row with a status of CLOSE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93608/discussion-between-jeroen-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working answer.

See this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/febde/24

```
SELECT ticket.ticketid,
   count(rr.relatedreckey) AS children,
   count(wo.id) AS wo,
   count(tt.id) AS sr
FROM ticket
INNER JOIN relatedrecord rr ON rr.recordkey = ticket.ticketid
AND rr.class = ticket.class
LEFT JOIN child1 wo ON wo.id = rr.relatedreckey
AND wo.class = rr.relatedrecclass
AND wo.status = 'CLOSE'
LEFT JOIN child2 tt ON tt.id = rr.relatedreckey
AND tt.class = rr.relatedrecclass
AND tt.status = 'CLOSE'
GROUP BY ticket.ticketid 
HAVING (count(wo.id) + count(tt.id)) = count(rr.relatedreckey);
```

basically it counts for each related type the number of the closed records and compares it to the total number of relatedrecords. If they are the same, all relatedrecords must be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Still not totally sure what you want for results but I think this might be it.

```
select *
from
(
    select t.ticketid
    from ticket t
    join relatedrecord rr on rr.recordkey = t.ticketid and rr.class = t.class
    join child1 c1 on c1.id = rr.relatedreckey 
        and c1.class = rr.relatedrecclass
        and c1.status = 'CLOSE'
    group by t.ticketid
    having MAX(c1.status) = MIN(c1.status)
    UNION ALL
    select t.ticketid
    from ticket t
    join relatedrecord rr on rr.recordkey = t.ticketid and rr.class = t.class
    join child2 c2 on c2.id = rr.relatedreckey 
        and c2.class = rr.relatedrecclass
        and c2.status = 'CLOSE'
    group by t.ticketid
    having MAX(c2.status) = MIN(c2.status)
) x
group by ticketid
```

Comment: no, this is not correct. It will also show tickets that have both closed children and children of a different status. In this case it will include the 1187 which is not correct. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/febde/7

Comment: I updated the post with a resultset that I want from that data.

Comment: Right but an explanation of WHY is what I need. I am guessing at the business rules.